# List VMs and their cluster

Tags: powershell, vsphere, powercli

I'd like to be connected to multiple VIservers and list all the VMs + their respective clusters. Is this possible?

I've gotten as far as `Get-VM | Select Name,VMHost`. What property in place of VMHost would list the cluster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try that

```
Get-VM | Select-Object -Property Name,@{Name=’Cluster’;Expression={$_.VMHost.Parent}}
```

which I found [here](https://psvmware.wordpress.com/tag/get-cluster-name-for-vms-in-powercli/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your use case you could also get the VMs if you know the cluster:

```
Get-Cluster | Get-VM
```